# How do I implement Dash/Plotly checklist persistence on a layout with multiple unique graphs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

My dashboard has a 2 x 2 graph layout with one checklist overlaid on each graph.

[image]

Each graph requires a unique ID, to be live-updated via callbacks.
These IDs are generated in a loop (e.g., graph-BMW, graph-MB, etc.).
Similarly, each checklist has a unique ID generated via the same loop (e.g., checklist-BMW, checklist-MB, etc.).
These IDs are passed to the *input* and *output* of the callback.

Graph data is calculated and the checklist value and figure are returned.

Since the checklist needs to be contained in the same DIV as the graph, they are nested and then unpacked in the layout.

All of this works perfectly, with one exception: `persistence` doesn't work.
If a checklist is clicked, I'm unable to retain the current (new) state when refreshing the page.
The checklist value always returns to unchecked, as it seems to be reset.

How can I resolve this?

A stripped-down version of the application:

```
cars = ['BMW', 'MB', 'AUDI', 'FIAT']

app3 = dash.Dash(__name__)

for car in cars:
    graph = 'graph-' + car
    checklist = 'checklist-' + car

    @app3.callback(Output(checklist, 'value'),
                   Output(graph, 'figure'),
                   Input(checklist, 'value'),
                   Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
    def update_charts(checklist, n_interval, c=car):
        data = get_car_data(c)
        df = calcs_on_car_data(data)

        fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['A'].values))
        return checklist, fig

list_graphs = []
for car in cars:
    list_graphs.append([html.Div(className='box',
                                 children=[html.Div([
                                     dcc.Checklist(id='checklist-' + str(car),
                                                   options=[{'label': '', 'value': 'on'}], value=[],
                                                   persistence=True),
                                     dcc.Graph(id='graph-' + str(car))])
                                 ])
                        ])

app3.layout = html.Div([
    *[j for i in list_graphs for j in i],  # unpacking a nested list
    dcc.Interval(id='interval-component', interval=300000, n_intervals=0)
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app3.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Check out this issue/PR https://github.com/plotly/dash/pull/903

Comment: thanks for the pointer. What's your opinion: is this a lost cause at this point?

Comment: I remember having faced the same issue and resolving it with some very ugly/hacky solution. But it was some 2 years back.

Comment: your code doesnt seem to have get_car_data(c)  and calcs_on_car_data(data) functions. Do provide with sample data so I can help from my end

Comment: Why is `def update_charts` inside the (first) 'for' loop? Is that normal in [Dash](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plotly-dash/info)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the circular callback breaks the persistence functionality. Removing it by dropping the checklist output, persistence works as intended. Here is an [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example),

```
import plotly.express as px
from dash import dash, dcc, html, Output, Input


def make_car_card(car: str):
    graph_id = f'graph-{car}'
    checklist_id = f'checklist-{car}'
    card = html.Div(className='box',
                    children=html.Div([
                        dcc.Checklist(id=checklist_id,
                                      options=[{'label': '', 'value': 'on'}], value=[],
                                      persistence=True),
                        dcc.Graph(id=graph_id)])
                    )

    @app.callback(Output(graph_id, 'figure'), Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'), Input(checklist_id, 'value'))
    def update_charts(_, value, this_car=car):
        if 'on' not in value:
            return px.scatter()
        return px.scatter(px.data.iris(), x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", title=this_car)

    return card


# Create small example app.
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [make_car_card(car) for car in ['BMW', 'MB', 'AUDI', 'FIAT']] +
    [dcc.Interval(id='interval-component', interval=300000, n_intervals=0)]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the below steps

- Make use of session variable to store checklist value
- once page refresh is completed(all page elements are reloaded), trigger a call to access session variable and assign value to relevant checklist.